# getting key $k_{2}$ somehow definitely compromise authentication scheme and attacker can see cipher text now...so not secure

Tags: encryption, authenticated-encryption, chosen-ciphertext-attack, integrity, semantic-security

I was going through this question of nested encryption:

Given $\Pi$ =  $({Gen}, {Enc}, {Dec})$ is authentication encryption we have designed new scheme $\Pi^{'}$ =  $({Gen^{'}}, {Enc{'}}, {Dec{'}})$ and which follows:
$\mathrm{Gen^{'}}(1^{n})$ gives uniformly random keys $(k_{1},k_{2}) = \{0,1\}^{n} \times \{0,1\}^{n}$.
And $\mathrm{Enc^{'}}((k_{1},k_{2}),m)$ =$\mathrm{Enc^{'}}(k_{2}, \mathrm{Enc}(k_{1},m))$ And deccryption algorithm  $\mathrm{Dec^{'}}((k_{1},k_{2}),m)$ gives $\mathrm{Dec^{}}(k_{1}, \mathrm{Dec}(k_{2},m))$ if $\mathrm{Dec}(k_{2},c) \ne \perp $ else $\perp$ otherwise. Proof this is not authentication encryption if attacker gain access to $k_{2}$ but not $k_{1}$.

My intuition is getting key $k_{2}$ somehow definitely compromise authentication scheme and attacker can see cipher text now...so not secure but how to go towards formal proof.

getting key $k_{2}$ somehow definitely compromise authentication scheme and attacker can see cipher text now...so not secure

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: the question is how to formally proof if attacker gain access to k2 but not k1 this scheme defined $\Pi_{'}$ is not authenticated encryption. @tylo

Comment: This looks like a homework question. So you might first want to present what you tried so far and why it does not work. And the question should probably be more specific, because right now this looks to me like "do my homework for me".

Comment: "getting key k2 somehow definitely compromise authentication scheme and attacker can see cipher text now...so not secure" here you are mixing up concepts for confidentiality and integrity. The authentication part does not hide the message from the attacker. If you want to break the authentication part, then looking at ways for the attacker to break the encryption part is going the wrong way. Since this is explicitly authenticated encryption, the attack is very likely to target the authentication part.

Comment: @tylo i am presenting my intuition so that someone can guide me ...how to reach solution because i have no exposure to these king of question....but i am wondering why people like you is  replying something absurd ....and i should say even in first post i have mention complete question ..you did not understand the question then and now also....so you are replying anything.....i request you if you do not know anything related to question please do not reply anything....

Comment: and for you information it is question 9.6 of boneh soup book ..which i am practicing....not from any other souce

Comment: Comments are for feedback on questions, and my comments so far are not absurd. There is actually no question formulated in all your text. And homework questions that just paste the question and do not present your own effort are considered a community-specific closing reason. As it is right now, the question is not good. And in my last comment, I gave you a hint how to attack that exercise, if you didn't notice.

Comment: at that time your hint did not appear..by the way thanks for your time....and suggestions. And do not assume anything from your side.....just please see book and question number i mentioned you will find there ,it has 3 parts , i managed to solve first and struggling here so i asked.....and i asked because previously i saw some discussion on that book questions .....not just randomly.....

Comment: I don't have that book, but it does not really matter where it's from. Questions on a site like this should ideally be stated in a way that might help others as well, and exercises and puzzles require you present some effort to solve it first. It is not enough to say "I can't solve it". Show what you tried.

Comment: well bro i have no way to show you my efforts...…anyway leave it …have a nice day.